# Create html page (admin friendly)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

We want to display the Salesforce record as a PDF which it's had a table and image. The admin able to construct the table, header logo and apply styles. This is our use case. What we are thinking, use the rich text editor (i.e. third party library) and it has drag and drop functionality too for drag the value of the column. We have planned to achieve this using a [WYSIWYG editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/). But unfortunately it doesn't support in lightning cause of locker service. Anyone knows alternative library to support in lightning?